# Non Modal Bootstrap Wizard

Tags: forms, twitter-bootstrap, user-interface, wizard

Please do let me know what I need to do to make the wizard window in the following example, https://github.com/amoffat/bootstrap-application-wizard, to not be modal but load itself when the page loads.

Any assistance will be highty appreciated.

Melroy

Answer (score 0):

This is no longer relevant as it has been completed

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old post, but the solution is available in the bootstrap 3 branch

https://github.com/amoffat/bootstrap-application-wizard/tree/bootstrap-3

This can be enabled by setting the isModal property to false in the wizard constructor.

```
var wizard = $('#satellite-wizard').wizard({
   keyboard : false,
   contentHeight : 400,
   contentWidth : 700,
   isModal:false
});
```

Strangely, the code to support this is not available in the plugin source delivered with the distribution on the download link. However, the minified version (bootstrap-wizard.min.js) contains the feature.

```
<script src="../src/bootstrap-wizard.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```